# Model Derivative API - get object properties with objectid returning 404 error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I followed the instructions outlined in 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-all-dbid-without-enumerating-model-hierarchy

I am able to get the model object tree and see the object id's i want to get properties for.

but when i take the object id and submit a query parameter i get a 404 status code back.

the text on the request returns :
{"message":"The requested model contains too many objects to retrieve hierarchy/properties. Please contact your next level support for further assistance."}

sample of my query in python to the end point

[Sample query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXqe.png)

Comment: Could you share some codes about how you call the API `GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties`? Have you also tried to call it in this way `GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties?objectid={objId}` mentioned in this blog? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-objectid-query-parameter-model-derivative-properties-api

Comment: Could you share the use case while calling the API `GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties`?